# When is the VSTO-Runtime needed when using a VSTO-AddIn?

Tags: vsto, add-in, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have a **VSTO-Add-In for Outlook** and need the information when i have to provide the **[VSTO-Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48217)** with the installation of the Add-In.

I have already found this [article](http://www.xltoolbox.net/blog/2015/01/net-vsto-add-ins-getting-prerequisites-right.html) describing the prerequisites but I could construct cases which do not fit this description:

The article says "If Office 2010 Service Pack 1 (version 14, build 6029) or any newer Office version is installed, Office will take care of configuring the VSTO runtime."
=> This is telling me I do not need to provide the *VSTO-Runtime* in this case.

In the case that I have installed *Office 2010* and manually install the [ServicePack 2](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=39667) I have the buildversion **7015** in my Outlook which is a greater version than **6029**.
[image: Version shown in Outlook]

My installer recognizes this and does not provide the *VSTO-Runtime*.

But on starting *Outlook* after the installation I get an error saying, the .vsto-file could not be read.
[image]

This error only disappears after installing the *VSTO-Runtime*. Then the AddIn works fine.

What are the real cases in which i need to provide the *VSTO-Runtime*?

Comment: Interesting question... I was not aware of the fact that with some version of Office the VSTO runtime installation could be omitted, I have always bundled the VSTO runtime in my wix bundle installers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using windows installer, just add it as prerequisite, which will create a Setup.exe, and add it as Launch Condition in your installer to show an error message, that Setup.exe should be run, or just make the Setup.exe run always, it will launch your .msi

[have a look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx) - I guess this is also valid for Office 2013 .. just use the right components IDs !

Comment: Thanks for this information but I am using the NSIS-Installer.
That might also be the reason for me having this problem.

Comment: maybe you could use the windows installer only to generate the setup.exe, and run this too as as step (maybe called checking dependencies) in your installation ?!